# ImportError: No module named 'multiprocessing.forking'

Tags: python, django, python-multiprocessing

I'm running Python 3.5 and trying to run some code from [this django app](https://github.com/antoinemartin/django-windows-tools) in the command line and this has been happening:

```
C:\Users\username\Envs\mysite> python service.py --startup=auto install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "service.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django_windows_tools.service import DjangoService,test_commands
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django_windows_tools\service.py", line 39, in <module>
    import multiprocessing.forking
ImportError: No module named 'multiprocessing.forking'
```

I'm not really sure what could be causing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

python `v2.6/2.7` have `forking.py` installed by default, but not `v3.5.1`

```
[root@localhost usr]# find /usr -name multiprocessing
/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing
/usr/lib64/python3.5/multiprocessing
[root@localhost usr]# find /usr -name forking.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py
```

python3.5.1 have no forking.py for some reasons, the package you ran, does not support python3, you may report issue on git repo or install it with python2.

```
[root@localhost usr]# python3
Python 3.5.1 (default, Mar  4 2016, 15:21:15)
[GCC 6.0.0 20160302 (Red Hat 6.0.0-0.14)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> import multiprocessing.forking
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'multiprocessing.forking'
```

While python2 has no problem

```
[root@localhost usr]# python2
Python 2.7.12 (default, Sep  2 2016, 14:46:00)
[GCC 6.1.1 20160621 (Red Hat 6.1.1-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> import multiprocessing.forking
```

Comment: This explains how to use `multiprocessing.forking` in python3.4 onward [https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Multiprocessing](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Multiprocessing)